# How to check if hard disk was removed while in sleep mode?

Tags: storage, intrusion

Let's say that some malicious person extracts my hard disk (HDD or SSD) from my laptop, while it is in sleep mode. Is there a way to check for that event?

I am mostly interested for Ubuntu OS, but if there are differences between other operating systems, feel free to note.

Comment: IMHO, there's no way to detect this from the Operating System side without hacking the hard drive disk driver (and even with this, not sure if it's possible in **every** sleep mode: to ram, to disk).

I would think that the only way to detect such a threat would rely on the hardware embedded in some laptop and desktop (but not all) that detect if the machine has been opened. You usually get a warning during boot if so.

Comment: I am not sure if you can use smart to detect it. If the disk is in sleep it should exist info in the memory related with the mounted file system. If the disk is turned on this data will be in inconsistent state and might generate file system errors. I am not sure if they can be detected by smart or the operating system...

Comment: Other idea is to try to save the working time of the hdd using smart, that should change if the disk is removed and spin up in other computer so you can match with the information you had when it entered in sleep mode... (just a brainstorm) :)

Comment: You could theoretically modify the BIOS or even better ME/PSP/DASH to log these kinds of events.